# Why iterative std::max with 2 constants is faster than std::max with initializer list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, max, initializer-list

Compiler : Visual Studio 2019 , Optimization : (Favor Speed)(/O2)

In a loop (over 1 million cycles), I use std::max to find the maximum element among 10 elements.
When I use std::max iteratively, like

```
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    out = max(arr[i],max(arr2[i],max(....);
auto end= high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start).count()<<endl;
```

is much faster than

```
using namespace std;
array<int,10> arrs;
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
    arrs = {arr[i],arr2[i],....};
    out = max(arrs);
    }
auto end= high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start).count()<<endl;
```

Why is that ?
This is actually not a specific question for the example above.

Why

`constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );`

is much faster than

```
template< class T >
constexpr T max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
```

?

Comment: All questions concerning the speed of C++ must be accompanied by 1) The compiler used, 2) The version of the compiler used, 3) The compiler optimization settings when building the application, and 4) The entire program, including the timing code.  If any of these are missing, we have no idea if what you are showing us is valid.

Comment: One of them has to build a std::initializer_list, the other doesn't.

Comment: If you have an existing range of values, consider [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: A side note: in your 2nd snippet the assignment `out = ...` is not a part of the loop (despite the indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying all of the array elements when you are constructing an initializer list, which is going to incur more overhead.